# cant get ndb query results

Tags: html, class, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb, time-and-attendance

i just started learning python ndb i want to know how can i display students attending a selected course (filtering Attendance) then mark their attendance with a ardio button for each student,add the attendance value to the preveious one and finally save the result back to the datastore or print it to file

# -*- coding: cp1256 -*-

```
import webapp2
import os
import cgi
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template


class Student(ndb.Model):
    id = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    #courses= ndb.StructuredProperty(Courses, repeated=True) and attendance

class Course(ndb.Model):
    code=ndb.StringProperty()
    title=ndb.StringProperty()
    #time=ndb.TimeProperity
    #students= ndb.StructuredProperty(Students, repeated=True)
    #attendance  

class Attendance(ndb.Model):
        courseCode=ndb.StructuredProperty(Course)
        #course=ndb.StructuredProperty(Course, repeated=True)
        date=ndb.StringProperty()
        #studentID=ndb.IntegerProperty(repeated=True)
        student=ndb.StructuredProperty(Student, repeated=True)
        attendance=ndb.IntegerProperty(repeated=True)# for each student


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        #cerate ndb from file
        coursesfile = open('courses.txt', 'r').read()
        studentsfile = open('students.txt', 'r').read()
        dailyattendancefile = open('dailyattendance.txt','r').read()

        for line in coursesfile.split('\n'):
            line=coursesfile.split('\t')
            #stroe courses to datastore
            course=Course(code=line[0],title=line[1])#create Course entity
            course.put()

        for line in studentsfile.split('\n'):
            line=studentsfile.split('\t')
            student=Student(id=int(line[0]),name=line[1],email=line[2])
            student.put()

        for line in dailyattendancefile.split('\n'):
            line=dailyattendancefile.split('\t')
            attendance=Attendance(courseCode=Course(code=line[0]),date=line[1],student=Student(id=int(line[2])),attendance=int(line[3]))
            attendance.put()

#print to html to test
        #self.response.out.write("<tr><td>"+ course.code + "</td>")
        #self.response.out.write("<td>"+ course.title+ "</td>")
        #self.response.out.write("</tr>")            
        self.response.out.write("""
        <html>
        <body>
        <form method="post" align="left">
            <select align="center" name="course_code">
            <option value="cs681" selected>CS681</option>
            <option value="cs681">CS611</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

        """)
    def post(self):
#get info from user
        coursecode=self.request.get('course_code')
        #self.response.out.write(Attendance.courseCode.code)
        self.response.out.write(""" 
    <table  align="center" >
        <tr align="center">
        <td>Course code</td>
        <td>Student ID</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Attendance</td>
    </tr>
""")
        qry=Attendance.query(Attendance.courseCode.code==coursecode).fetch()
        for ent in qry:
            self.response.out.write('<tr><td>%s</td></tr>' %ent.courseCode)

        self.response.out.write("""
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
        """)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. I think you have a minor issue in your schema definition.

```
class Course(ndb.Model):
    code=ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    title=ndb.StringProperty()
```